# Every root of $x^n-1$ is simple in $ \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Let $p$ be a prime number s.t $p$ doesn't divide $n$. Show that every roots of $x^n-\overline{1}$ is simple in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

If $\overline {a} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ is a root of $x^n - \overline{1}$ then $a^n \equiv 1\pmod p$ and $\gcd(a,p)=1$. By Fermat's little theorem we have $a^{p-1} \equiv 1\pmod p$.

Ok, now I need to prove that if $\overline{b} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ is root of $x^n - \overline{1}$, that is, $b^n \equiv 1 \pmod p$, then $\overline {a} = \overline{b}$, that is, $a \equiv b\pmod p$. Can you give me a way to solve that?

Comment: $2^3\equiv4^3\equiv1\pmod7$ but $2\not\equiv4\pmod7$

Comment: so, the statement is false?

Comment: are you trying to prove $(x-a)^2\nmid x^n-1$?

Comment: Yes! Ok, understand that my idea was wrong

Comment: I've tried to use the division algorithm, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If $f(a)=0$, and $a$ is not a simple root, what can you say about $f'(a)$? (The formal derivative)

---

Define $f(x)=x^n-1\in\Bbb Z_p[x]$, and let the group-homomorphism $$\frac{d}{dx}:\Bbb Z_p[x]\rightarrow\Bbb Z_p[x]$$ be the formal derivative.

**Detecting multiplicity, and why it works**

> Let $f(x)\in R[x]$ be a polynomial in any polynomial ring over any commutative ring $R$. Suppose that $f(a)=0$, then $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$. Taking the formal derivative we get $$f'(x)=g(x)+(x-a)h(x)$$ If $f'(a)=0$, we get that $g(a)=0$, and so $(x-a)\mid g(x)$, in other words $$(x-a)^2\mid f(x)$$

**Applying the test**

> Firstly, $f(0)\neq 0$, since $0^n-1\neq 0$, so assume that there is a non-zero $a\in\Bbb Z_p$ such that $f(a)=0$. Assume also, for sake of contradiction, that $f'(a)=0$. Then $$\frac{d}{dx}(x^n-1)=nx^{n-1}\\na^{n-1}=0$$ Thus $p\mid n$ or $p\mid a$. Both are impossible, so $f'(a)\neq 0$. And we're done!

Comment: Can I use the formal derivative in $\mathbb{Z}_p$??

Comment: @Joãonani Yes! Consider it as a group homomorphism $\frac{d}{dx}:\Bbb Z_p[x]\rightarrow \Bbb Z_p[x]$

Comment: Indeed, you know that if all roots of the polynomial are simple in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then the polynomial and its formal derivative are relatively prime!

Comment: ok, if I use the formal derivative then I get the result easily... but  where I use that $p$ doesn't divide $n$?

Comment: @J  did you try taking the derivative mod $p$?

Comment: ok, Now I got it! $p|na^n$ but $p$ doesn't divide $n$ neither $a^n$.